# Azure web jobs and always on

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have read that web jobs require "always on" enabled
http://blog.amitapple.com/post/73574681678/git-deploy-console-app/

I have a free web site and my job continues to run also after 20 minutes. As I'm writing, it runs since more than two hour. Why?  Perhaps because my site has traffic so the app-pool continue to be "up and running"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your job continued to run more than 20 minutes there is no promise from Windows Azure Websites for that, so if you need to rely on that you'll need to enable "always on", also free sites have a limitation on the amount of CPU they can use so even if your web job will be always on, this limitation will most likely be reached.

One reason why your job kept going could be because you kept checking it (in the dashboard), looking at the dashboard for the continuous jobs will also start them if they went down (due to "always on" not set).

Comment: After a whole night the job is still running. During the night I sleeped and I haven't used the dashboard. :) My site has low traffic from internet, but there is always traffic. So, I imagine, the traffic maintains my web app running. So webjobs continue to run. Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes, but be aware (and monitor) that your site may be stopped if cpu quota is reached.